# Parse properties string in an array to For Each loop

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get information about the battery in my laptop by using VBScript.

It is more properties. I want to parse `arrayItems("Name","Availability","BatteryStatus","Chemistry")` for each `objItem`.

For example:

```
For iii = 0 To UBound(arrayItems)
    WScript.Echo "Result of iii:" & objItem.arrayItems (iii)
Next
```

I do not want to enter manually as `"Availability: " & objItem.Availability`, `"BatteryStatus: " & objItem.BatteryStatus`, ...

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Battery",,48)
For Each objItem In colItems
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    WScript.Echo "Availability: " & objItem.Availability
    WScript.Echo "BatteryStatus: " & objItem.BatteryStatus
    WScript.Echo "Chemistry: " & objItem.Chemistry
    WScript.Echo "DesignVoltage: " & objItem.DesignVoltage
    WScript.Echo "EstimatedChargeRemaining: " & objItem.EstimatedChargeRemaining
    WScript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly seems to be the problem you are having?  You haven't explained what you are really trying to do very clearly, or what the actual output of your code is, and why it isn't what you are after.  Have a read of [ask] and see if you can edit the question so it's clearer?

Comment: @Dave I edited my ask. Please review and help me.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to call each attribute of the object individually, but rather do a *print all properties* in a loop? In that case you should use reflection to inspect the available properties of the object. Not sure how to do that in vbscript though (or if it is even possible)

Comment: @Geert Bellekens - My mind as your description. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be done via the object's [`properties_` property set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbempropertyset):

```
arrayItems = Array("Name", "Availability", "BatteryStatus", "Chemistry")
For Each objItem In colItems
    For Each name In arrayItems
        WScript.Echo name & ": " & objItem.properties_(name)
    Next
Next
```