# Join value of the properties in the For Each loop to one line output

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmic

Sorry for my bad English.

At here [Parse properties string in an array to For Each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338588/), with support from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/
I was able to read the battery information. But it is just separate information, so how do we assemble it and export the results into one line.

```
Dim strResult, objItem, arrayItem
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Battery")
arrayItems = Array("Name", "Availability", "BatteryStatus", "Chemistry")
For Each objItem in colItems
     For Each arrayItem In arrayItems
        strResult = Join(objItem.Properties_(arrayItem))
    Next
    WScript.Echo strResult
Next
```

And it shows empty result of the output.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` to start with. Sweeping errors under the rug isn't helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the properties and join them into a string.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objItem, arrayItems, strComputer
Dim objWMIService, colItems, arrResult, i

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

'The third parameter 48 for 'ExecQuery' is the combination of wbemFlagForwardOnly + wbemFlagReturnImmediately
'see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemservices-execquery#parameters
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Battery",,48)
arrayItems = Array("Name", "Availability", "BatteryStatus", "Chemistry")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'create/clear an array to store the various pieces of information
    ReDim arrResult(UBound(arrayItems))
    For i = 0 To (UBound(arrayItems))
        ' Sometimes the WMI property returns a Null value (Nothing)..
        If Not IsNull (objItem.Properties_(arrayItems(i))) Then
            arrResult(i) = objItem.Properties_(arrayItems(i))
        Else
            arrResult(i) = "Unknown"
        End If
    Next
    'as example I'm using the Tab character to join the pieces
    WScript.Echo Join(arrResult, Chr(9))
Next
```

Comment: The code runs very well. I really want you to have a lot of health to support people.

Comment: Please don't ask another question in the comments.

Comment: @Orion8 I could replicate that error (on my machine using Win32_Volume and the "Availability" property). As it turns out, WMI can return Null values for some properties, so the code must make sure it can handle that. I have edited my answer to check on Null values.